# "size" command for memory layout (text,data,bss)

Tags: c, gcc, memory, memory-management

I want to understand memory storage segments with 'size' command in c language. I did those respectively :

---

#### **`file1.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

- `gcc -o size1 file1.c`
- `size size1.exe`

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
7446    1404     244   12708    24b4 ./size1.exe
```

---

#### `file2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int glb; /* Uninitialized variable stored in bss*/
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

- `gcc -o size2 file2.c`
- `size size2.exe`

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
7446    1404     244   12708    24b4 ./size2.exe
```

---

In size of `file2.c`, I was expecting `bss` segment increase but didn't change. Why did this happen?

global variable added, but bss segment didn't increase

---

**Edit :**

<sup>* Using object file instead of .exe solve my problem but now .bss increase 16 instead of 4</sup>

*Question evolved to why .bss increase of 16 instead of 4?*

Comment: Use command `objdump --syms size2` and check the output, do you find `glb` in it?

Comment: @SafelyFast Thank you for answer. Can we disable this optimization?

Comment: @H.S. Yes, there is `glb`

Comment: @SafelyFast: Unlikely in this case.  First, no `-O` option was used so optimization is not being done.  Second, since `glb` is global the compiler can't know whether it might be used in another module, so it must not optimize it out in the compiler pass.  Link-time optimization would be able to detect that it is not, and optimize it out, but LTO has not been enabled here.

Comment: What is the command in Windows that equivalent to size in Linux? I searched even using Copilot, it said there is no its equivalent. But if there is no, it is quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason is "alignment".  There may be objects in the program that need alignment to a multiple of a certain number of bytes, which may require padding to be inserted (bytes that are allocated but not used).  A newly added object may happen to be placed in a region that would otherwise be used for padding, in which case it does not actually increase the overall size of the section.

As a simple example, suppose that your original program had two objects in the `.bss` section (e.g. used by startup code), a 2-byte object `my_short` requiring 2-byte alignment, and an 8-byte object `my_long` requiring 8-byte alignment.  The linker might happen to place them in memory as follows:

```
0x0 - 0x1: my_short
0x2 - 0x7: (padding)
0x8 - 0xf: my_long
```

A total of 16 bytes is used, including 6 bytes of padding.

Now you add a new object `glb`, 4 bytes, requiring 4-byte alignment.  Depending on the order in which the linker processes its object files, it could be placed after `my_short` but before `my_long`.  In that case the memory map might look like:

```
0x0 - 0x1: my_short
0x2 - 0x3: (padding)
0x4 - 0x7: glb
0x8 - 0xf: my_long
```

The total is still 16 bytes, but now with only 2 bytes of padding.

You can use the `-Wl,-M` option (that is one option with a comma in it, no spaces) to emit a linker map for each version, and you should be able to see it happening.

---

On my system, I get a 8-byte `.bss` section for both versions.  The linker script used by `ld` (which can be printed by using `-Wl,--verbose`) includes an `ALIGN` directive at the end of `.bss`, so that `.bss` always ends up as a multiple of 8 bytes. (There is a FIXME comment in the script file indicating that one of the programmers was unsure why they did that or if it was really necessary.)

Besides `glb`, there is only 1 byte in `.bss` (used by startup code), so following that is either 7 bytes of padding, or else 3 bytes of padding followed by `glb`.